# pop up menu with long press gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios and also core animation so I'm doing some tests to get used to it. 
I've got a menu I'm trying to create by doing a long press gesture. I want the button to by animating up and then animate down and then disappear. I got the appearing part working, but I can't figure out how to make it disappear. It also doesn't let me animate my imageView in my UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded statement. Basically, I have two questions:

1. How can I animate the button going down when the long press is released?
2. How can I only make one of these buttons instead of them appearing every time I do a long press?

Here's what I have in my .m

```
-(void)onPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longpress{

CGPoint touchCenter = [longpress locationInView:self.view];

UIImage *plus = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:plus];

CGRect imageViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);
imageViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(touchCenter.x - imageViewFrame.size.width / 2.0f, touchCenter.y - imageViewFrame.size.height / 2.0f);
imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;

if (longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform moveTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -40);
        imageView.transform = moveTrans;
    }];
    NSLog(@"Long press");
    return;
}else{


if (longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform moveTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 40);
        imageView.transform = moveTrans;
        NSLog(@"long press done");
    }];

}


}
```

}

and my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
    CAShapeLayer *layer;

}
@property(nonatomic) float angle;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm now sure what you want to do. But I modified some of your code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *moveView;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recoginzer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onPress:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recoginzer];
}

- (void)onPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longpress {
    CGPoint location = [longpress locationInView:self.view];
    if (longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (!self.moveView) {
            self.moveView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 100, 100)];
            self.moveView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [self.view addSubview:self.moveView];
        } else {
            self.moveView.frame = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 100, 100);
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
            CGAffineTransform moveTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -40);
            self.moveView.transform = moveTrans;
        }];
        NSLog(@"Long press");
    } else if (longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
                CGAffineTransform moveTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 40);
                self.moveView.transform = moveTrans;
                NSLog(@"long press done");
            }];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: That's that the behavior I'm looking for but how would I apply this to a uibutton instead of a uiview?

Comment: @StevenP. just add the button to that view.