# How to add an app after the long press call button swift

Tags: swift, call

I need to add my app to the table that is shown at the screenshot after the long tab on the call button. Can you tell me which feature I need to use?

**See example-**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792216/pop-up-menu-with-long-press-gesture.        check this answer.

Comment: You know, I need to put my application in the calllist table as shown in the link to the screenshot, I cannot find the name of the function that will help me implement it.